# Subclass UITableView for built-in search

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Would it be possible (or advisable) to attempt to subclass a UITableView to have built-in search functionality?

There are two reasons I wanna do this:

**Reuse**: I could use the same subclass at multiple places in my project with different data-sources.
**Cleaner code**: It would de-clutter my view controller. All the plumbing for implementing search would be neatly incapsulated in the subclass implementation.

Any ideas how one would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UISearchDisplayController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

From Apple doc,

> A search display controller manages display of a search bar and a
>   table view that displays the results of a search of data managed by
>   another view controller.
>
> You initialize a search display controller with a search bar and a
>   view controller responsible for managing the original content to be
>   searched. When the user starts a search, the search display controller
>   is responsible for superimposing the search interface over the
>   original view controller’s view and showing the search results. The
>   results are displayed in a table view that’s created by the search
>   display controller. In addition to the original view controller, there
>   are logically four other roles. These are typically all played by the
>   same object, often the original view controller itself.

It can be implemented as,

```
searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                         initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

`UISearchDisplayController` itself encapsulate all the normal search features. If you want you can subclass it to achieve whatever you are planning to do. You can use this in any class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should ask for clarification: do you want the user's search to simply scroll to a row in the table, or do you want it to filter the rows, displaying only rows that match the search term?

Assuming you want it to filter the rows...

It would be pretty complicated to make a `UITableView` subclass to do this, because you'd need to interpose your own private `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in front of the “user” data source and delegate.

It also might be rather inefficient, depending on how you get the data for the table view.  If the table view can have thousands of rows, and they come from (say) a SQLite database or Core Data, the data source can search more efficiently for matching rows.  In the table view, you'd have no choice but to iterate through the rows one by one, checking each for a match.  Or you'd have to extend the data source protocol to give the table view a way to pass the search string to the data source... which seems like it defeats the goal of putting the searching in the table view.

If you tell us more about where the data comes from for your various table views, we might be able to give you better advice.